# Jenkins: Change Build Status when Pipeline is Aborted by Milestone

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

When a Jenkins build is aborted by a ***milestone()*** command, I would like to have the build status **SUCCESS**.

Currently we have 3 stages where we need to deploy our application to: INT, PRE, PROD. Our CI process looks as follows:

Build -> Test -> Build Docker -> Deploy to INT -> **Approve for PRE** -> Deploy to PRE -> **Approve for PROD** -> Deploy to PROD

In the approval steps for PRE and PROD looks like this:

```
/************** PRE **************/
stage('Approval for PRE') {
    try {
        timeout(time: approvalTime, unit: approvalTimeUnit) {
            input 'Do you approve the deployment to PRE?'
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        finishBuild = true

        // return statement just ends stage
        // => pipeline continues after stage
        // => return must be called again outside stage or node again
        return
    }
}

// Stop build if flag was set
if (finishBuild)
    return

// MILESTONE stops build with status = "NOT_BUILT"
milestone()
```

I already tried to put the milestone() command inside a try&catch block but that didn't work out. Are there any other solutions for that?

**INTENSION**

Currently we do not deploy everything right to PROD and most of the time the approval will be ignored and we stay on INT. With the maturity of the project this might change.

But that said, if we go on from time to time all previous builds end up with a grey status and it's just confusing for my team mates: Nothing went wrong, all tests are green, and no one aborted but the build is no longer green.

Comment: I'm pass for the same problem! do you have any news??